# What's wrong with my iteration through an array of JSON objects in Jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have objects similar to this...

```
{
    a: {
        aa: 1,
        ab: 2
    },

    b: {
        ba: 4,
        bb: 3
    }
}
```

...but they are in an array.

In Jade, I have a table displayed like so...

```
table
  tr
    td aa
    td= data[0].a.aa
  tr
    td ab
    td= data[0].a.ab
  tr
    td ba
    td= data[0].b.ba
  tr
    td bb
    td= data[0].b.bb
```

It displays correctly. Even when I replace the 0 with a 1. So both objects are visible.

Now, I want to show a table of multiple objects in `data` by looping through. I tried the following and it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? It seems so simple.

```
for i in data.length
  table
    tr
      td aa
      td= data[i].a.aa
    tr
      td ab
      td= data[i].a.ab
    tr
      td ba
      td= data[i].b.ba
    tr
      td bb
      td= data[i].b.bb
```

No tables appear. The page shows up blank.

In case it matters, I'm using Express.js to generate the array of objects. The page is just  a view that is rendered. No ajax or other variables involved.

Comment: Just `for i in data` maybe?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I didn't think of that. It worked. I changed `data[i]` to just `i` as well. I still have no idea what was not working before. You can post this as an answer if you want and I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the loop should be:

```
for i in data
  table
    ...
```

You were trying to loop on `data.length` which is a single value (the length of the array).

Comment: But then I was also using `data[i]`. I guess that doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: The right side of "in" takes an array (or other container), and it runs the loop body for each thing in the array. You weren't passing in the actual array, just a single number (which happened to be the length of the array). So there was nothing for the loop to loop through.